# regexp replace until comment

Tags: python, regex, replace

I have this file:

```
 # blah blah blah DO NOT REPLACE blah blah
 blah blah blah
 blah blah REPLACE # comment comment
 REPLACE blah blah
```

comments begin with "#", I want to replace the keyword where it isn't inside a comment.

I'm using python, how do I do this?

Comment: Where's you code?

Comment: `str="Boy, am I ever glad that I can use '#' in strings!"`

Answer (score 3):

Don't use regular expressions. Instead, split the lines at the `#` character and just work with the first parts:

```
>>> lines = '''
...  # blah blah blah DO NOT REPLACE blah blah
...  blah blah blah
...  blah blah REPLACE # comment comment
...  REPLACE blah blah
... '''
>>> [l.split('#', 1) for l in lines.split('\n')]
[[''], 
 [' ', ' blah blah blah DO NOT REPLACE blah blah'], 
 [' blah blah blah'], 
 [' blah blah REPLACE ', ' comment comment'], 
 [' REPLACE blah blah'], ['']]
```

You can now write code (perhaps using another list comprehension) to replace the occurrence of `REPLACE` in the first parts and rejoin the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Niklas B, you don't need regexp for your problem.

You could use some like this:

```
>>> f = lambda text, sub, repl: \
... '\n'.join([line.split('#')[0].replace(sub, repl) + '#' + line.split('#',1)[1] \
... if '#' in line else line.replace(sub, repl)
... for line in text.split('\n')])
```

and then, if you have

```
>>> text = """# blah blah blah DO NOT REPLACE blah blah
...  blah blah blah
...  blah blah REPLACE # comment comment
...  REPLACE blah blah"""
```

and want to replace "REPLACE" for '%%%%' you could use function f like:

```
>>> print f(text, 'REPLACE', '%%%%')
# blah blah blah DO NOT REPLACE blah blah
 blah blah blah
 blah blah %%%% # comment comment
 %%%% blah blah
```